# Wordpress - Custom fields & Class Identifiers

Tags: css, wordpress, content-management-system, field

In Wordpress - how do you assign a class to custom fields?  I am attempting to target multiple custom fields with custom CSS, but seem unable to give them separate classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help.
I've since discovered a great bit of syntax that accomplishes the job.

```
<?php echo '<li class="address">' . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Address', true) . '</li>'; ?>
```

This pulls in one single custom field at a time.  In the example above, my custom field title was 'Address'.  The  will wrap the content from that field - thus accomplishing the task of wrapping each custom field in it's own class.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the BEST solution, but is worth a shot, I'd do a loop per field so your get_posts would look like this:

```
$args = array(
    'meta_key' => 'custom_attribute',
    'meta_value' => 'value1',
    );
$value1 = get_posts($args);

$args = array(
    'meta_key' => 'custom_attribute',
    'meta_value' => 'value2',
    );
$value2 = get_posts($args);
```

So that will give you 2 arrays, each one pulling different posts, from that you can do a foreach going through each array (value1 and value2) and adding classes as needed.